# Which CMS features do you need in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system

I am going to write a ContentManagementSystem for RubyOnRails for administration of static pages.

Which features do you prefer to appear in this CMS?
What do you think might be helpful for daily work?

Best regards

Comment: Finally! I've been waiting for someone to invent the wheel :-)

Comment: (I do like the question, though. But you should maybe be a little more specific, and you should definitely turn this into community wiki)

Comment: Of course, there will be a project site including a wiki. But at the moment, there is no community, so I thought it would be better to ask here;)

Comment: balpha means to enable the community wiki functions for your STACKOVERFLOW-QUESTION (look for it in edit mode)

Answer (score 2):

Just a good read on Rails & CMS

[The Ruby on Rails CMS dillema](http://aaronlongwell.com/2009/06/the-ruby-on-rails-cms-dilemma.html)

Comment: Looks like an interesting link, a pity it is dead. Is there an updated version to it?

Answer (score 0):

something like an drag & drop Template builder.

Userstory :

- Create new Page
- Take some boxes from the sidebar and put it on an empty page
- click the box
- add content , pictures etc. to this box
- save & publish

.. yeah i want something like this :-) inspired by Wordpress Widget Management.

Answer (score 0):

Look around for existing Rails CMSs likes Radiant, BrowserCms,

Also study Drupal, Wordpress and Joomla in php, they seem to be doing pretty great as CMS's and are awesome at that.

Answer (score 0):

A Django-like in feature but Rails-ish in nature Admin interface. That is the talk of the town these days..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: http://shane-hippo.blogspot.com/2009/08/hor-experiment-2.html

This experiment shows how you can set up your own application within 15 minutes, with Hippo on Rails.